# Is an implementation of blinded encryption/decryption mechanism exists?

Tags: secret-sharing

I want to use 2 semi trusted servers, to decrypt a secret for a user but I don't want those servers to have access to the plain text.

Those server need to be able to "partially" decrypt and let the user finish the decryption.

One way could be : 
User crypt a secret with server A
User crypt result with server B

User decrypt result with server B
User crypt (?) result with one time key
User decrypt result with Server A
User decrypt (?) result with one time key => User got plain text

Thanks !

Comment: What's the goal here?